# Intellisense for model properties not working in View for HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, html-helper

My question is simple and might not be important to other coders, but it would really help a lot if some one can explain to me why I can't get the `Intellisense` working When using `DisplayNameFor`. It is working on `DisplayFor` or other models, but not this one. While it is not helping me to get the correct properties, it is however telling me when there is no such name of a property.

> Error is Does not contain any definition for "insert variable here"

Well that is reassuring, why not tell me what is available then?

```
@model IEnumerable<RMQGrainsBeta.Models.ExpenseIndexViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ExpensesIndex";
}

<h2>ExpensesIndex</h2>


<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SONumber)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateProcessed)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stats)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalExpense)
    </th>
</tr>
```

Example if I type in `model.` <- this will not give me any Intellisense.
But if I continue to type in it, `model.To` <- it will tell me that there is no definition of "To" in the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `model` in `(model => model.*)` is `IEnumerable<ExpenseIndexViewModel>` which does not have properties `SONumber`, `DateProcessed`, etc. Those are properties of `ExpenseIndexViewModel`.

You'll need to iterate over the collection

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => item.SONumber)
}
```

Comment: Meaning, the Intellisense can't walk through the IEnumerable and Check? SAD. Simple and great explanation. With a Work around to. Thanks :D

Comment: @Jasen, I agree with you and that explanations sounds fine as well. But for HtmlDisplayNameFor in the headers section, you normally wont iterate over... And even if you see examples in asp.net mvc site, they wouldnt have iterated over for the headers.. Though it initially throws error and later automatically corrects itself.. why it so?

Comment: some extension methods like as `DisplayNameFor` has two overload versions. if you write `@Html.DisplayNameFor(` you will see there are two available overload versions: one for `HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>>` and one for `HtmlHelper<TModel>`. the correct version will be called based on given arguments

Comment: @TechQuery you are right about we normally wont iterate over IEnumerable models. see my comment above

Comment: Thanks @saeedserpooshan

Comment: I have the same issue. I am following a course on Core MVC and while in the video I see intellisense is working for the guy when he is typing e.g. "@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name);" but it doesn't work when I do. Code compiles & works fine tho. I still don't understand why it's not working for me.